# Lotto Game Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created an array containing 6 numbers. I have generated a random number between 1, 40 but every number shows in order. I need it to read just 6

```
        static void Main()
    {
        int temp;
        int number = 0;
        int[] lotto = new int[6];

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 40; i++)
        {
            number = 0;
            temp = rand.Next(1, 40);

            while (number <= i)
            {
                if (temp == number)
                {
                    number = 0;
                    temp = rand.Next(1, 40);
                }
                else
                {
                    number++;
                }                    
            }
            temp = number;
            Console.WriteLine("your lotto number is " + number);
        }
            Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You're never adding anything to the `lotto` array. I'm also not sure why you're calling random twice but never doing anything with the value.

Comment: is `temp = rand.Next(1, 40);` should be  `number = rand.Next(1, 40);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        int number = 0;
        int[] lotto = new int[6];

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 6; ctr++)
        {
            number = rand.Next(1, 41);

            while (lotto.Contains<int>(number))
            {
                number = rand.Next(1, 41);
            }
            lotto[ctr-1] = number;
            Console.WriteLine("Your lotto number is: " + number);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

If you want to sort it, you can do it like this
`int[] sortedCopy = lotto.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray();`
But you will need
`using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 0):

A simple Linq with order by `Guid.NewGuid()`?

```
var lotto = Enumerable.Range(1, 40)
                      .OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid())
                      .Take(6)
                      .ToArray();
```